# MS access update query issue with date range

Tags: ms-access

I'm using this update query in MS access 2016
Update sampledata set VALUE= '" & Me.value & "' where Day between '" & Me.dayfrom & "' and '" & Me.dayto & "';
The strangest problem m facing is- It is considering the form values for start and end date but however updates records only for the start date. Example. If dayfrom is 01-Nov-2021 and dayto is 30-Nov-2021, the query is updating records of only 01-Nov-2021.
When I pass the day from as 30-Nov-2021, it is updating records for the whole month.

Note: This doesn't happen when I directly pass the values in the query, it happens only when i Pick data from FORM and apply it in query.

Answer (score 0):

```
   UPDATE table3 
   SET table3.status = "YES"
   WHERE (((table3.transactiondate)>=[FORM]![Form3]![startdate] And 
   (table3.transactiondate)<=[FORM]![Form3]![enddate]));
```

When you run the query, two pop up input box will open, in the first one, enter the value for start date, e.g 01/01/2022  , in the second one enter the end date e.g 02/28/2022.  Do check the date format in use by your system so you can be sure you are entering the date parameter in the right format.

Answer (score 0):

As is, the date values will be casted to strings using your Windows settings.

So, force a format on the string expressions to have true string expressions for the date values:

```sql
Sql = "Update sampledata " & _
    "Set VALUE = '" & Me!value.Value & "' " & _
    "Where Day Between #" & Format(Me!dayfrom.Value, "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "# And #" & Format(Me!dayto.Value, "yyyy\/mm\/dd") & "#;"
```